# QTextEdit и абзацный отступ

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qtextedit

Как добавить абзацный отступ в данном виджете по типу, как в ворде? 
Чтобы при копировании не добавлялись никакие пробелы, табы...
Данный способ не работает: . 
Текст также идет без абзацного отступа.

На картинке пример из ворд как примерно нужно:

[image: Пример как нужно в WORD]

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(608, 349)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(143, 50, 311, 211))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 608, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {text-indent: 20px}")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше объясните что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick Вот код:

Comment: @S.Nick Добрый день, обновила вопрос. Добавила код:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже в `setStyleSheet` - **`text-indent`** не работает, 
а если в `setHtml`, то работает, попробуйте.

> [**html : QString**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop)
>
> Это свойство предоставляет интерфейс `HTML` для текста редактирования текста.
> Входной текст интерпретируется как форматированный текст в формате `html`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(650, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(143, 50, 311, 211))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("""
            QTextEdit {    
                color:red;
                font-size: 18px;
                text-indent: 70px;     /*  <---- похоже тут не работает */ 
                border: 15px solid green;
            }""")
            
        self.textEdit.setHtml("""
            <p style='-qt-block-indent: 0; 
/* а тут работает --> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv   */
                      text-indent: 20px;'> 
Testing. Как добавить абзацный отступ в данном виджете по типу, как в ворде? 
Чтобы при копировании не добавлялись никакие пробелы, табы... 
Данный способ не работает: . Текст также идет без абзацного отступа. 
На картинке пример из ворд как примерно нужно
</p>
        """)
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо. Но новая проблема появилась. Это работает только при ручном вводе. А если скопировать текст с того же ворда - форматирование снова не работает:)

Comment: @ВалерияГригорьева пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Первый абзац я добавил программно. ВТОРОЙ - скопировал!!! Третий - набрал руками. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Да, я обязательно помечу.

Comment: По поводу абзаца - если текст удалить и вставить, то форматирование пропадает